# Divider operator within an external stylesheet with PHP

Tags: php, css, operators, stylesheet

**TL;DR: I use PHP inside an external stylesheet, but it doesn't recognize the '/' as a PHP divider operator, this messes up my CSS. Any help is appreciated**

I'm working on a simple website which loads the menu items dynamically from a page table in the database. with a recursive algorithm I get all the pages, and the child pages at the right place.

In this function I count the amount of main menu items.

I do this because I need to make every `<li>` in the main menu `<ul>` such a width that it covers the whole width of the menu bar. I want this to be done dynamically so that if more pages are added as a main menu item, nothing has to change, only an insert to the database.

Now my question: I read right [here](http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum83/2201.htm) that it's possible to configure Apache so that it reads CSS as PHP files. Works as a charm, nothing wrong. Now I have

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url().'css/css-reset.css'.'?item_count='.$menu_count; ?>" />
```

in my header (as you can see I pass the menu item count as a post variable). This also works. My CSS:

```
<?php Header ("Content-type: text/css");?>
<?php
$wrapper_width = 900;
$menu_item_count = (int)$_REQUEST['item_count'];
$menu_item_width = $wrapper_width / $menu_item_count;
?>

/*lots more boring CSS */

div#wrapper
{
text-align:left;
width:<?php echo $wrapper_width.'px'; ?>;
}

div#menu a
{
display:block;
height:1.7em;
width:<?php echo $menu_item_width.'px'; ?>;
}
```

And this is where a weird thing comes up. If I set the `$menu_item_count` to be just an int (ex: `$menu_item_count=150`) it works as it should. But as soon as I use the divider operator between the two variables the CSS gets messed up. other operators work.

The way I see it, the divider operator is special to CSS (because of the comments?) and it doesn't read it as a PHP divider operator but as a CSS symbol.

I've tried putting it in a function, the function works, but the divider operator messes it up again.

So my questions are: Anyone ever worked with PHP in external stylesheets? If so, can you help me figure out this problem?

Comment: can you inspect the generated output? your description of the problem is lacking, to say the least.

Comment: Your PHP is processed way before the css is ever interpreted. Can you elaborate on how it "gets f'ed up"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what went wrong: I added the query string to the wrong CSS file. Nothing wrong with the division operator or anything, just my stupid mind not working too well from staring at my monitor too long.

Answer (score 1):

Check the output from your php /css script. You can do this by entering the address to your script in a browser, and if you have set up apache correctly, the results of your php calculations should be there. My guess is that the division operator may return some decimal number which is not compatible with css. Try this:

```
$menu_item_width = (int)$wrapper_width / $menu_item_count;
```

Comment: So ok, sorry to all that i didnt describe it as good as i shoul;d. and i shouldve tought of checking the css output myself *facepalm* 
this: `$menu_item_width = (int)$wrapper_width / (int)$menu_item_count;` outputs: ` <br />
<b>Warning</b>:  Division by zero in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\hanseclub-limburg.nl\docs\css\css-base.css</b> on line <b>5</b><br />`

So something goes wrong while getting the $request, ill try $post in a sec. Because the menu_item_count in my header.php echoes 5. as it should

Answer (score 0):

The Division symbol is running within PHP and shouldn't be causing you any trouble.  Might I recommend using HEREDOC instead of opening and closing the PHP like that.  It could make it easier to manage.

```
<?php 
header ("Content-type: text/css");
$wrapper_width = 900;
$menu_item_count = (int)$_REQUEST['item_count'];
$menu_item_width = $wrapper_width / $menu_item_count;

echo <<<EOL
/*lots more boring css */

div#wrapper {
  text-align: left;
  width: $wrapper_width px;
}
EOL;
?>
```

To solve your problem, can you post the output of that file?